# c#: SerializableAttribute

Tags: c#

The `SerializableAttribute` class is explained on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx).  In the start it is written:

> Indicates that **a class can be serialized**

Can anybody expalin what this means (the bold part). I am not clear about it.

Comment: [`In computer science, in the context of data storage and transmission, serialization is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and "resurrected" later in the same or another computer environment.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing an object (an instance of a class) means turning it into something that can be written on a file or broadcasted over the network, such as an XML file (Xml serialization) or a Byte array (binary serialization).

This needs to be a two way operation, so you must be able to "Deserialize" the object.

In order to be serializeble an object must contains just serializable fields/property or fields marked as not serialized. For example a Sql connection is not serialized (it would make no sense deserializing it somewhere else...)